# While loop won't work with Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, while-loop

I am trying to make it so a user can add multiple products to a Paypal checkout. the name="item_name_1" in the Paypal form has to increment by 1 so that it is added to the cart. So i thought of adding 1 to a variable ( $number) every time the while loop reaches the end, but it isn't working.

While loop

```
//for paypal order number
$number = 0;

while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($runquery)) {  

    $number =  $number + 1;

    $prodid = $row['PRODUCT_ID'];
    $price = $row['PRICE'];
    $image = $row['IMAGEID'];
    $prodname = $row['NAME'];
    $stallname = $row['STALL_NAME'];
    $quantity = $row['PRODUCTQUANTITY'];
    $day = $row['DAY'];
    $time = $row['TIME_CHOICE'];
    $total = $row['TOTALPRICE'];

    $subtotal = $price * $quantity;

    echo '   <tbody>
          <tr>';

    echo  '<td> <img src="' . $image . '" height="50" width="50"/></td>';
    echo  '<td>' . $prodname . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $stallname . '</td>';
    echo  '<td> ' . $quantity . '</td>';     
    echo  '<td>&pound;' . $price . '</td>'; 
    echo  '<td>&pound;' . $subtotal . '</td>';        
    echo'     </tr>';

    //increments number for paypal orders
    echo'
    </tbody>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Clear Order</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Collection Day</th>
        <th>Collection Time</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Pay</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td><form method="post" action="clearorder.php"><input type="submit" name="clearorder" value="Clear" /></form></td>
      <td></td>';
    echo '<td>' .$day . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$time . '</td>';
    echo '<td>&pound;' .$total . '</td>';  
    echo'

Paypal form

        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
          <td>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email"';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $number . '" value="' . $prodname . '">';
    echo'<input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $number . '" value="' . $quantity . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $number . ' value="' . $price . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">';

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't have `<td>` inside `<form>`. `<td>` has to be a child of `<tr>`. Put the form around the whole table.

Comment: @Barmar Still not working. I think that $number is the problem. But not quite sure what that problem is.

Comment: I can't run your code so it's tough to troubleshoot for you, but I can tell you the loop doesn't look correct.  You have the PayPal form as a whole inside the loop.  The only part that should be in the loop are the item_name, quantity, amount, lines.  Things like currency_code, business, cmd, etc. should only be in the button one time, but the way you're doing this looks like it would be in there multiple times.  Can you provide a copy of the end result you're getting here?